# Upgradable packages preventing ubuntu 20 upgrade to 22

Tags: apt, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I am using ubuntu 20.04 and I want to upgrade to 22.04. This requires to have upgraded all the packages. After apt update, two packages (r-core-base and r-core-dev) can be upgraded but the upgrade fails because these packages can not be installed:

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base-core : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.35) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.9 is to be installed
               Depends: libicu70 (>= 70.1-1~) but it is not installable
               Recommends: r-recommended but it is not going to be installed
```

Apparently, libc6 >=2.35 is only available for 22.04, but without it I can not upgrade. What can I do?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you are trying to install the 22.04 version of `r-base-core` while the rest of your system is still on 20.04. Either revert `r-base-core` and `r-core-dev` to the 20.04 version or uninstall those packages completely until after your release-upgrade to 22.04 is complete.

Comment: would it work with a downgrade?

Comment: Remove `r-core-base`, perform the upgrade, and install R once again

Comment: I had to do this and it worked. Uninstalling r and then upgrading. Thanks